# Protocol buffers negative int32/int64 encoder's specifications are fuzzy

Tags: protocol-buffers

In the encoder specs of protocol buffers https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding , it is said that :

> If you use int32 or int64 as the type for a negative number, the resulting varint is always ten bytes long – it is, effectively, treated like a very large unsigned integer

Okay, that look nice, but with a 10 bytes long varint, you can store a 70 bits long integer, and the type is 64 bits. Thus, there are 6 bits not used... should these bits be set to 1 or 0 ?

to summup, with int32/64, should `-1` be encoded as

`FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 7F`

or

`FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 01`

?

Comment: See this explanation: https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/fU0SVchScA0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit 64 and above should be zero. So, in C++, you would encode an int64 by casting it to uint64, then encoding that like any other unsigned integer (this is in fact what the Protobuf C++ library does). Keep in mind that `int32`s need to be sign-extended to 64 bits.

Comment: Note also that e.g. Google's C++ protobuf will decode non-sign extended negative int32 correctly, but e.g. Python protobuf will not. Wouldn't be surprised if a few implementations out there do this incorrectly, I'm guilty of atleast one (https://code.google.com/p/nanopb/issues/detail?id=97)

Comment: So I guess this means -1 will be encoded as `FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 01`?